# meaning of allow unsafe code in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, unsafe

i need to understand, what is meant by allow unsafe code?

[image]

and there is safe and unsafe code ?

Comment: it allows you to use the `unsafe` statement - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)

Comment: As in [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)